# html5 canvas image grid in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

I'm trying to build an image grid with canvas, but I'm not sure how to perform operations when a particular image is clicked. I want to achieve functionality like in this website https://big.dk/#projects but it's too complicated for me to grasp, I'm comfortable using javascript preferably Angularjs instead of JQuery if possible. I'm thinking of using tables to align images in a grid, can we achieve this kind of functionality without using canvas ? any suggestions would be of great help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can make this without using canvas either using bootstrap grid or with any other grid system you like,
Probably this can help you jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/2/

And you should use transition css for smooth image zooming(resizing) on mouse hover.

Comment: Hi, I want the images to align vertically -> yearly basis just like in that website, do you have any idea how to achieve it ? thank you